# Regex to match a subpattern within some range from the start

Tags: regex

Is there an regex to match the following pattern?

- Starts with `TTG`
- Contains `TATGAT` within letter range(20, 35) from the first pattern(`TTG`)
- Contains `ATG` within letter range(27, 42) from the first pattern(`TTG`)

The example pattern is the following:

> ...**TTG**ATGCTCGATCTATCGATAG**TATGAT**CTAGACT**ATG**...

I tried something like `TTG.{17,32}TATGAT` to match the first subpattern `TATGAT`, but can't use this kind of approach when it has multiple subpatterns, like in the question.

I'm working in JS to use this regex

Comment: please show your attempted regex

Comment: Also do mention which language you want to write this regex in your question.

Comment: @anubhava I can match the second pattern like: `TTG.{17,32}TATGAT`, but can't manage the third one

Comment: @SnowSuno, kindly do add your code(shown in comments) and which language you need also in your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I added it. Sorry for my bad english. I'm not quite sure if my grammar is correct.

Comment: @SnowSuno Instead of using a regex only solution, you could try to do a lose regex validation and combine it with some string operations

Comment: @degant I know how to handle the problem combining other string operations, but I’m asking whether it is possible using pure regex.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using lookaheads like this:

```
(?=TT[GT][ACT][ATGC]{16,25}TATGAT)[ATGC]{27,39}ATG
```